# parent class not returning value to child class

Tags: c++

I am just learning c++. It is known that child's member is not available to parent, child has availability. But Here, why `c1.showval` shows b value is 0, though it has been set 10 already in `B` class.

```
class A{
    int a;
    public:
        int b;  
};

class B:public A{
    public:
        int setVal(int x){
            b = x;
        }
        void prntVal(){
            cout << "The value is " << b;
        }
};

class C:public B{
    public:
    void showVal(){
        cout << "The value is " << b;
    }
};

int main(){
    B b1;
    C c1;
    b1.setVal(10);
    c1.showVal();
}
```

Comment: You set value for `b1` but print it for `c1`. Note that `c1`'s value is uninitialised when you print it.

Comment: `setVal` is declared to return an `int` but it doesn't, so your program has [_undefined behavior_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: `b1` and `c1` are different instances

Comment: Not even two `B` instances would share non-`static` member variables.

Answer (score 1):

Although `C` is derived from `B`, they do not share their members. You set the value `b` to `10` for b1, but `c1`'s `b` stays uninitialised.

Answer (score 1):

b1 and c1 are different objects. b1 is an instance(object) of class B and c1 is a *different* instance(object) of class C. Therefore b1.b and c1.b are different variables and hence b1.setVal(10) only sets the value of b1.b and not c1.b. If you want the instances(objects) to share the same value for A::b you can make it static.

```
class A{
  int a;
public:
  static int b;  
};

int A::b;
```